# Displaying user current location on map with phoneGap

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to displaying a user current location on a map using phoneGaps getCurrentPosition function but I don't just want the users latitude and longitude I want their actual location example state they are current in, street name, country name ect. If anyone could point me in the correct direction I would greatly appropriate it (ebooks, weblinkes, blog post, code snippets anything). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to reverse geocode the lat/lng into an address. Google has an API for that: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding